# WCF: Missing System.ServiceModel.Configuration.* types on .NET Core

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-core, wcf-configuration

WCF on netcore is only client-side only implementation, I see. But where are configuration types for getting access to client configuration?

Does WCF on netcore support configuration at all?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Most of the stuff in that namespace is directly related to the app.config / System.Configuration based config model that doesn't exist in core anyway

Comment: System.Configuration.* stuff does exist in dotnet. See System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.